# New Controller - No Route Matches update, edit, show or destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having some difficulty getting all the RESTful routes to be setup correctly. I've taken the simplest of simple steps in my app so far.

1. Create new rails app
2. Create new controller with RESTful actions
3. Add `resources` to `routes.rb`

And yet 4 out of my 7 actions fail the default tests. Can anyone please explain why?

```
rails generate controller Employees new create update edit destroy index show
```

And here's the corresponding controller, `employees_controller.rb`

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
  end

  def update
  end

  def edit
  end

  def destroy
  end

  def index
  end

  def show
  end
end
```

Now I add the resources to `routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :employees

end
```

All the routes seem to be there, based on the output of `rake routes`

```
       Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                   Controller#Action
    employees GET    /employees(.:format)          employees#index
              POST   /employees(.:format)          employees#create
 new_employee GET    /employees/new(.:format)      employees#new
edit_employee GET    /employees/:id/edit(.:format) employees#edit
     employee GET    /employees/:id(.:format)      employees#show
              PATCH  /employees/:id(.:format)      employees#update
              PUT    /employees/:id(.:format)      employees#update
              DELETE /employees/:id(.:format)      employees#destroy
```

But now when I run the default tests, I get 4 errors:

```
# Running:

.EEEE..

Finished in 0.267712s, 26.1475 runs/s, 11.2061 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
EmployeesControllerTest#test_should_get_update:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"update",       :controller=>"employees"}
    test/controllers/employees_controller_test.rb:15:in `block in   <class:EmployeesControllerTest>'


  2) Error:
EmployeesControllerTest#test_should_get_destroy:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"employees"}
    test/controllers/employees_controller_test.rb:25:in `block in <class:EmployeesControllerTest>'


  3) Error:
EmployeesControllerTest#test_should_get_show:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show",     :controller=>"employees"}
    test/controllers/employees_controller_test.rb:35:in `block in <class:EmployeesControllerTest>'


  4) Error:
EmployeesControllerTest#test_should_get_edit:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"employees"}
    test/controllers/employees_controller_test.rb:20:in `block in <class:EmployeesControllerTest>'

7 runs, 3 assertions, 0 failures, 4 errors, 0 skips
```

Lastly, here is the contents of `employees_controller_test.rb`. As I said, these are the default tests auto-created by Rails upon generation of the controller.

```
require 'test_helper'

class EmployeesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get new" do
    get :new
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get create" do
    get :create
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get update" do
    get :update
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get edit" do
    get :edit
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get destroy" do
    get :destroy
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get show" do
    get :show
    assert_response :success
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you show what `employees_controller_test.rb` looks like?

Comment: Yes, I've already got it :) See the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to dimakura's answer you have to change some routes in your test

the update method is a `put` (or a `patch` for partial changes in rails4)

```
  test "should get update" do
    put :update
    assert_response :success
  end
```

and for your edit, delete and show routes, the `id` is missing

```
  test "should get edit" do
    get :edit, id: 2
    assert_response :success
  end
```

Comment: Is i possible the failing tests are failing because I don't actually have any members in the Employees table yet? Show, update, edit, and destroy would seem to require at least one member of the table on which to operate, right?

Comment: @user3325401 you dont need any objects in your database. you can stub or mock objects (i'm using rspec for testing). but your edit route looks like `/product/1/edit` and for this you need an id

Comment: Thank you very much! Finally got all 7 tests passing!

Answer (score 0):

Your controller test probably looks like:

```
class EmployeesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get create" do
    get :create
    assert_response :success
  end

  # other tests not shown
```

end

You should change it to this:

```
class EmployeesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get create" do
    post :create
    assert_response :success
  end

  # other tests should be changed accordingly
end
```

Use `patch` or `put` method for `update`, and `delete` for `delete` actions.

Comment: Interesting! As you probably guessed, I'm a Rails beginner, so let me think out loud here....it looks like you just change the 'get' to a 'post'? Why would the auto-created test use the incorrect method - or if not incorrect, at the very least, a method that causes the test to fail?

Comment: Auto create doesn't know what you mean :) If you want models + controllers + tests created with correct methods, then you should probably generate `rails g scaffold Employee ...`

Comment: Well I just changed the get to post for the update test, and it still failed. The create action does pass the tests.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Finally got all 7 tests passing! I think the trick was to add the id: field to the actions.